# How to get last 24 hours from current time-stamp?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to pull all data for the last 24 hours but starting from the current time. If the current date-time is 5/3 and the time is 11:30 then i want to pull the last 24 hours from 11:30.  The data type for date field is `datetime` and it has only the date and time values without the seconds. Here is my current query

```
select Name, Location, myDate from myTable where myDate>= getdate()-24
```

the query above is giving me everything but i only want from the current time.
this is how myDate look like in the table

```
 2015-03-05 10:30:00.000
2015-03-05 11:00:00.000
2015-03-05 11:30:00.000
2015-03-05 12:00:00.000
2015-03-05 12:30:00.000
2015-03-05 13:00:00.000
2015-03-05 13:30:00.000
2015-03-05 14:00:00.000
2015-03-05 14:30:00.000
```

Comment: Use dateadd() in a loop - unless you want them as a resultset in which case that would be useless but you can still use dateadd(d, -1, getdate()) - this comment doesn't make much sense, I've considered deleting it .. maybe I'm tired. You can use `dateadd()` instead of subtracting from a date - that way you can be more explicit in your intentions (`dateadd()` allows you to specify a unit such as hours/minutes/days etc)

Comment: You should really use dateadd instead of + or - operator just because it's so easy to misunderstand what the operator actually does.

Comment: `getdate()-24` ... minus 24 *what*? Hours, minutes, seconds, days, years, etc? Look up the `DateAdd()` function in the manual!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To be more explicit with your intentions, you may want to write your query like so:

```
 select Name, Location, myDate from myTable where myDate>= DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE())
```

[SQL Server DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is with:

```
select Name, Location, myDate from myTable where myDate>= getdate()-24
```

The -24 as this would be -24 days

try:

```
select Name, Location, myDate from myTable where myDate>= getdate()-1
```

An alternative would be to use the date add function:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp

```
DATEADD(datepart,number,date)
```

In your situation you could:

```
    select Name, Location, myDate from myTable where myDate>= DATEPART (dd, -1, GETDATE())
```

Where we are adding negative one dd (days)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server 2012 or above, you could ANSI interval literals instead of `dateadd()`:

```
select Name, Location, myDate from myTable
 where myDate>= getdate() - INTERVAL '24' HOUR;
```

If you want to be really ANSI standard, you can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `getdate()` ([the two are equivalent](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/12/20/sql-server-difference-between-current_timestamp-and-getdate-current_timestamp-equivalent-in-sql-server/)).

```
select Name, Location, myDate from myTable
 where myDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '24' HOUR;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct, do you have any more information? I'm getting `Incorrect syntax near '24'`, and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210686/interval-is-not-a-recognized-odbc-date-time-extension-option) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/215139) says SQL Server just doesn't have the INTERVAL data type.