# Get last 7 days data from today 7am to last 7 days 7am

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-timestamp

I have a query that currently can view the timestamp between yesterday 7am and today 7am data. How do I extract the timestamp of last 7 day timestamp. For example, if today is 10th August 2022, I would like to see the data of 3rd August 7am to 10th August 7am data. This is my current SQL query:

```
  select TOP (10000000) id, PartNum, TimeStamp,Station
  from test_module
  where TimeStamp >= '2022-07-16 07:00:00' 
  and Timestamp <= '2022-07-17 07:00:00'
  order by TimeStamp asc
```

Comment: Whats the point of `TOP (10000000) `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Timestamp >= dateadd(hour, 7, dateadd(day, -7, convert(datetime, 
 convert(date, getdate()))))
 and Timestamp <= dateadd(hour, 7, convert(datetime, convert(date, 
 getdate())))
```

Answer (score 1):

`datetime`s can participate in addition. Thus, you can construct the day parts(remove the time first), and then add 7 hours as a `time`:

```
declare @start datetime = dateadd(day,-6,convert(datetime,(convert(date,getdate()))) + convert(datetime,convert(time,'07:00:00'))
declare @end   datetime = dateadd(day, 0,convert(datetime,(convert(date,getdate()))) + convert(datetime,convert(time,'07:00:00'))
```

Be careful tossing the term "timestamp" around in SQL Server, it could lead to...miscommunications...

Answer (score -1):

Can use `getdate()` function and for last 7 days, -7
For instance,

```
where DateCol between DateAdd(DD,-7,GETDATE() ) and GETDATE()
```

Comment: it will get all the data from last 7 days. I want the data till 7am today

Answer (score -2):

Try [dateadd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

See also thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882878/how-to-get-last-24-hours-from-current-time-stamp)

Comment: Answers need to be stand alone, using only links for reference.